# Applying Squeeze Principle

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I'm doing a university real-analysis course and just had a question about a limit and the squeeze principle.

Take...

$x_n = \frac{Sin(n)}{n}$

We know...

$\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0 $

Squeeze principle says...

$x_n \leq y_n \leq z_n$. Then $\forall n \geq N $

and that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $z_n \rightarrow x$ then Then $y_n \rightarrow x $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Therefore...

$\frac{-1}{n} \leq \frac{sin(n)}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Therefore by squeeze princible...

$\frac{sin(n)}{n} \rightarrow 0$

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: at some places, the phrasing is weird, but it is mostly correct

Comment: You are missing crucial details which is $ -1 \leq \sin(n) \leq 1$ then you proceed from this fact.